Fast way to generate hypergeometric random variables
I see some references on this
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233212638_Computer_generation_of_hypergeometric_random_variates
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gsl.git/tree/randist/hyperg.c
but they look inefficient enough that I'd be inclined to work with an algorithm that doesn't use a HyperGeometric RNG. Isn't there some approximation polynomial P[N,K](x) that I can apply to the uniform random-variable x over [0,1]?
This is pretty much beyond my math capabilities, and I have to wonder if it's been solved already.

I'm a little disappointed that I can't find existing topic-tags like "hypergrometric-distribution" and "random-number-generator", and am not positioned to be able to create them. Can one of you do this for me?

Any hypergeometric random variable takes values only in $\mathbb N,.$ The polynomial that takes $x\in[0,1]$ and delivers such a natural number I'd like to see. Also: you should use that and produce evidence that it is inefficient.

Do you have a reference for the algorithm? I just see the procedure declaration there.
The algorithms I've seen published, though, either used K bernoulli draws or approximated using some other distribution. I'm hoping there'd be some convergent series that could be improved just by including more terms.

I don't. Have you tried any of the algorithms that "look" inefficient?

On paper, yeah, and also they don't parallelize.
Back to the [0,1] -- I assume that some version of the Inverse Transformation Method would apply, with a discretization step somewhere.

There are many methods to parallelize algorithms. You don't say what you have in mind exactly. The python function I gave you is open source. What more do you need to find out its algorithm? Back to $[0,1],:$ another brainstorm of yours that would make for an almmost decent self contained MSE question when  the asker writes up some mathematical steps.

The Hypergeometric variable would be a step in another algorithm I'm looking at. If there's an O(1) way to do that, which I'd expect using Inverse Transformation and some polynomial approximation. The algorithms I've seen. though, involve iterations just to generate one variable. I'll dig into the Transform method and post some questions based on the formulation.

If I read right, this
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/src/distributions/random_hypergeometric.c
is just repeating uniform samples and making a count. My desire is to use the Hypergeometric variable as a way to avoid doing that, to solve a different problem.

I just did what I asked you to do yesterday. lol

The following code compare the runtime of

drawing $N=100,000$ uniforms and sticking them into the inverse CDF of the normal distribution which is your preferred way of generating RVs

calling the function hypergeometric to generate $N$ hypergeometric RVs


It appears that hypergeometric takes less than $0.03$ seconds while the other method takes around $10$ seconds.
import time
from numpy import random
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy.random import hypergeometric
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = time.time()

N = 100000
to_hist = list()
for i in range(N):
    u = random.uniform(0.0001,0.99999)
    n = norm.ppf(u)
    #to_hist.append(n)

end = time.time()

#plt.hist(to_hist,bins=40,fill=False)
#plt.show()

print( "{:10d} normals        , {:f} s".format(N,end-start) )

start2 = time.time()
h = hypergeometric(N/2,N,N/10,N)
end2 = time.time()

print( "{:10d} hypergeometrics, {:f} s".format(len(h),end2-start2) )

plt.hist(h,bins=40,fill=False)
plt.show()


print( h[0:10], max(h), min(h) )


Can you try commenting out the "n=nnorm.ppf(u)" part? I'd like to know how much of the cost is in the inverse-CDF calculation and how much is in the looping & calling.

Also, where is the source for that? If it's using a binary-search to invert the function, that would make it real slow...

@CarlPonder perhaps I could become your personal programmer now to test things that look inefficient on paper. Have you not even installed python yet? If you did I apologize. The code of hypergeometric is in C:\...\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numba\cpython\randomimpl.py.

I see the hypergeometric code in
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/src/distributions/random_hypergeometric.c
But I can't find the inverse-gaussian. It's under
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/
somewhere, right?
